# Hiding a button until a condition is met (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a fishing game, where I want a button to be hidden until the fish number reached 5. However, the button (set fish traps) does not seem to be hidden even the condition has been met...

```js
let fishNum = document.getElementById("fishNum");
let traps = document.getElementById("cm2Btn2");

function addFish() {
  let fishNum = document.getElementById("fishNum");

  count.innerHTML++;
}

if (fishNum > 2) {
  traps.classList.add('fadeOut');
}
```

```html
<div class="cLeftRight">
  <span id="fishNum">0</span>
</div>

<button id="cm2Btn" onclick="document.getElementById('fishNum').innerHTML++">Catch a Herring</button>

<button id="cm2Btn2">Set Fish Traps</button>
```

Comment: Your `if()` only runs once when page loads which is before any clicks occur

Comment: Right now you check to see if fishNum is greater than 2, and if so you add the class `fadeOut`. I don't see any css for styling the `fadeOut` class, and you do not check again anywhere other than the first run, where I believe you would want to check on a certain event.

Comment: First of all, you want to place the expression changing the button's visibility inside the function changing the number of fish (you do want to check (and run) that expression every time you add fish, right?). Secondly, if the button starts hidden, add the hiding class to it from the start and only remove it when there are enough fish. Last, but not least: are you sure adding the `fadeOut` class hides the button? You're not showing any CSS which would apply, to make that happen. Could you create a [mcve]?

Comment: I've cleaned up what you have and [made it work](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/3erct76f/). You need to pay a little bit more attention to detail. Cheers!

Comment: @tao I like your use of `cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)`, and it makes more sense game wise to show the button on 3 fish, but why put a snippet answer in the comments? It might make sense to add the answer using stack overflow's code snippet tool so the answer will be available into the future and others can suggest edits easily.

Comment: @async, I didn't add an answer as, In my estimation, this question doesn't meet the [SO] recommended quality standards. It's basically caused by a handful of minor mistakes/typos and lack of coding discipline. Therefore I personally consider it bloat (it doesn't hold significant teaching value for future users to be added to SO). Which is why I chose not to answer it. At the same time, I wanted to help Chris move forward on his path of learning web development. If you read [answer], you will notice you are encouraged not to answer low(er) quality questions.

Comment: Ref business logic (showing the button after a number of fish have been caught): read the question carefully. That's what OP actually wants.

Comment: That makes sense, good catch on the logic needs. I can see why you wouldnt add an answer. However it still feels a bit strange to say you wouldn't leave an answer in the answer area, but you would in the comments, but I can understand your reasoning. I think I will also leave my answer as I believe it does fit in the SO question guidelines, especially with the edits applied. Thanks for the insight 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240153/discussion-between-tao-and-async-await).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example only checks the value of fishNum on the initial load, and fishNum is not a number but an element from the dom. Your addFish function is never used, only the inline js from the html. Your addFish function increments a variable called count, which is never defined. There is no css for the class `fadeOut` so the item will not fade out even if the class were added.

Please see my demo, which is a rough fix of what you were attempting to do. Some things that I would change moving forward, instead of incrementing the HTML of fishNum, I would have a variable in js that you increment, and update the screen to reflect what is happening in your js.

At the core of answering this question, I believe you are looking for the css property `transition` and the html attribute `disabled`. We can use js to enable the button when we add the `fadeIn` class, and make it so we transition gradually from 0 to 1 opacity.

```js
let fishNum = document.getElementById("fishNum");
let traps = document.getElementById("cm2Btn2");

function addFish() {
  fishNum.innerHTML++;
  
  if (fishNum.innerHTML > 4) {
    traps.classList.add("fadeIn");
    traps.disabled = false;
  }
  
}
document.getElementById("cm2Btn")
  .addEventListener("click", addFish);
```

```css
#cm2Btn2 {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

#cm2Btn2.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cLeftRight">
  <span id="fishNum">0</span>
</div>

<button id="cm2Btn">Catch a Herring</button>

<button disabled="true" id="cm2Btn2">Set Fish Traps</button>
```